# Cannot access sum function in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I just want to do a simple sum like I would have done in sql. I am using EF6 by the way and T4 templates if that makes any difference. Database First design.

> Select SUM(Payments) from tblPayemtns where customerNo=2322

I thought it would have been a matter of doing something like this.

```
 var _myPayments = from c in portalEntities.tblPortalPayments.Where(p => p.userId == _userID)
                          group by c.paymentDate
                          select new
                          {
                              Sum = 
                          };
```

But I cant seem to get access to the sum arggergate function when I go c.Sum its not in the list just eh field names are available me am I calling my linq wrong to be able to do this what I want is Sum= sum(c.paymentsToDate).

Before someone asks and I no they well this is my portal entties function it just returns a new isntance of entities for me to keep my code clean.

```
public portalEntities _portalEntities;
   public portalEntities portalEntities
    {
        get
        {
            if (_portalEntities == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    _portalEntities = new portalEntities();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }

            return _portalEntities;
 }
```

Comment: i dont want this questio be avial for a bounty i dont think it warnts the option being there how do i sort this ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You just need to sum the grouped result for the Payment column:</strike>

```
var _myPayments = from c in portalEntities.tblPortalPayments
                                          .Where(p => p.userId == _userID)
                  group c by c.paymentDate into g
                  select new
                  {
                       Sum = g.Sum(x=>x.Payment)
                  };
```

More simpler way is to select the column and then Sum the rows by leaving the unnecessary group by clause:

```
var Sum = (from c in portalEntities.tblPortalPayments
                                   .Where(p => p.userId == _userID)
           select c.Payment).Sum();
```

or another way can be:

```
var Sum = portalEntities.tblPortalPayments
                        .Where(p => p.userId == _userID)
                        .Sum(x=>x.Payment);
```

Comment: Thank you how would I return the int of that by the as all i want to do is return that value  within the method

Comment: Thanks very much can you explain as to why you have to do that the group by i persume it a thow back to old sql

Comment: That group by is not needed according to the sql you shown in question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do smth like this:

```
var _myPayments = 
         from c in portalEntities.tblPortalPayments.Where(p => p.userId == _userID)
         group by c.paymentDate
         select new
         {

         }.Sum();
```

You can also make use of lambda-expressions to do the query:

```
var _myPayments = portalEntities.tblPortalPayments.Where(p => p.userId == _userID).Sum(x => x.Payments);
```